# If I modify a static variable of a class does it get shared by previous instance of the class?

Tags: java, static

If I modify a static variable of a class does it get shared by previous instance of the class or only the new instance of the class.

I was just doing RMI and I have a class with static variables which I register to RMI registry. If I update the static variable by calling the RMI object it gets updated but if I update it by classname then check the value of the variable from the RMI object it gives me the old value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If class `A` has a static variable `s`, then all instances of `A` in a given JVM will share that static variable.  The JLS guarantees this.

Possible explanations for what you are seeing include:

- You have managed to load class `A` multiple times in the JVM, using different classloaders.  That will give you different `A` classes, as far as the type system is concerned, and each one will have different static variables.
- You are actually talking to instances of `A` in a different JVM in the "by RMI" and "by classname". cases.  The classes `A` in the different JVMs do not share static variables.
- Various problems with your edit / build / deploy / run cycle.

Comment: Most probably the 2nd case. RMI registry is on another JVM.

Comment: Maybe.  It depends on exactly how you are accessing the static for / from the object in the registry.  An MCVE would clarify that.